# Array Index Out Of Bounds when running Logistic Regression from Spark MLlib

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I'm trying to run a Logistic Regression model over the KDD dataset using Scala and the Spark MLlib library. I have gone through multiple webs, tutorials and forums, but I still can't figure out why my code is not working. It must be something simple, but I just don't get it and I'm felling blocked at this moment. Here is what (I think) I'm doing:

1. Create a Spark Context.
2. Create a SQL Context.
3. Load paths for training and test data files.
4. Define the schema for the data to work with. That is, the columns we are going to use (names and types) with the KDD dataset.
5. Read the file with training data.
6. Read the file with the test data.
7. Filter input data to ensure only numeric values for every column (I just drop the three StringType columns).
   8.Since Logistic Regression model needs a column called "features" with all features packed within a single vector, I create such column via the "VectorAssembler" function.
8. I just keep the columns named "label" and "features", which are essential for the Logistic Regression model.
9. I use the "StringIndexer" function in order to transform the values from the "label" column into Doubles, otherwise Logistic Regression complies saying it can't work with StringType.
10. I set the hyperparameters for the Logistic Regression model, indicating the Label and Features columns.
11. I attempt to train the model (via the "fit" method).

Bellow you can find the code:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{StringIndexer, VectorAssembler}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

object LogisticRegressionV2 {
  val settings = new Settings()  // Here I define the proper values for the training and test files paths

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("LogisticRegressionV2").setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

    val trainingPath = settings.rootFolder + settings.dataFolder + settings.trainingDataFileName
    val testPath = settings.rootFolder + settings.dataFolder + settings.testFileName

    val kddSchema = StructType(Array(
      StructField("duration", IntegerType, true),
      StructField("protocol_type", StringType, true),
      StructField("service", StringType, true),
      StructField("flag", StringType, true),
      StructField("src_bytes", IntegerType, true),
      StructField("dst_bytes", IntegerType, true),
      StructField("land", IntegerType, true),
      StructField("wrong_fragment", IntegerType, true),
      StructField("urgent", IntegerType, true),
      StructField("hot", IntegerType, true),
      StructField("num_failed_logins", IntegerType, true),
      StructField("logged_in", IntegerType, true),
      StructField("num_compromised", IntegerType, true),
      StructField("root_shell", IntegerType, true),
      StructField("su_attempted", IntegerType, true),
      StructField("num_root", IntegerType, true),
      StructField("num_file_creations", IntegerType, true),
      StructField("num_shells", IntegerType, true),
      StructField("num_access_files", IntegerType, true),
      StructField("num_outbound_cmds", IntegerType, true),
      StructField("is_host_login", IntegerType, true),
      StructField("is_guest_login", IntegerType, true),
      StructField("count", IntegerType, true),
      StructField("srv_count", IntegerType, true),
      StructField("serror_rate", DoubleType, true),
      StructField("srv_serror_rate", DoubleType, true),
      StructField("rerror_rate", DoubleType, true),
      StructField("srv_rerror_rate", DoubleType, true),
      StructField("same_srv_rate", DoubleType, true),
      StructField("diff_srv_rate", DoubleType, true),
      StructField("srv_diff_host_rate", DoubleType, true),
      StructField("dst_host_count", IntegerType, true),
      StructField("dst_host_srv_count", IntegerType, true),
      StructField("dst_host_same_srv_rate", DoubleType, true),
      StructField("dst_host_diff_srv_rate", DoubleType, true),
      StructField("dst_host_same_src_port_rate", DoubleType, true),
      StructField("dst_host_srv_diff_host_rate", DoubleType, true),
      StructField("dst_host_serror_rate", DoubleType, true),
      StructField("dst_host_srv_serror_rate", DoubleType, true),
      StructField("dst_host_rerror_rate", DoubleType, true),
      StructField("dst_host_srv_rerror_rate", DoubleType, true),
      StructField("label", StringType, true)

    ))

    val rawTraining = sqlContext.read
      .format("csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .schema(kddSchema)
      .load(trainingPath)

    val rawTest = sqlContext.read
      .format("csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .schema(kddSchema)
      .load(testPath)

    val trainingNumeric = rawTraining.drop("service").drop("protocol_type").drop("flag")

    val trainingAssembler = new VectorAssembler()
      //.setInputCols(trainingNumeric.columns.filter(_ != "label"))
      .setInputCols(Array("duration", "src_bytes", "dst_bytes", "land", "wrong_fragment", "urgent", "hot",
      "num_failed_logins", "logged_in", "num_compromised", "root_shell", "su_attempted", "num_root",
      "num_file_creations", "num_shells", "num_access_files", "num_outbound_cmds", "is_host_login",
      "is_guest_login", "count", "srv_count", "serror_rate", "srv_serror_rate", "rerror_rate", "srv_rerror_rate",
      "same_srv_rate", "diff_srv_rate", "srv_diff_host_rate", "dst_host_count", "dst_host_srv_count",
      "dst_host_same_srv_rate", "dst_host_diff_srv_rate", "dst_host_same_src_port_rate", "dst_host_srv_diff_host_rate",
      "dst_host_serror_rate", "dst_host_srv_serror_rate", "dst_host_rerror_rate", "dst_host_srv_rerror_rate"))
      .setOutputCol("features")

    val trainingAssembled = trainingAssembler.transform(trainingNumeric).select("label", "features")

    val labelIndexer = new StringIndexer()
      .setInputCol("label")
      .setOutputCol("indexedLabel")
      .fit(trainingAssembled)

    val trainingData = labelIndexer.transform(trainingAssembled).select("indexedLabel", "features")
    trainingData.show(false)

     val lr = new LogisticRegression()
      .setMaxIter(2)
      .setRegParam(0.3)
      .setElasticNetParam(0.8)
      .setLabelCol("indexedLabel")
      .setFeaturesCol("features")

    val predictions = lr.fit(trainingData)

    sc.stop()

  }
}
```

As you can see, it is a simple code, but I get a "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1" when the execution reaches the line:

```
val predictions = lr.fit(trainingData)
```

And I just don't know why. If you had any clue about this issue, it would be very appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I am seeing the same behaviour..did you find a fix for this?

Comment: Not yet. I've tried everything that came to my mind, but I still don't know what I'm doing wrong :-(

Comment: Could you reduce your features one by one and retry it? Same error am I seeing when using `model.coefficients`. It happens that I have some features for which every training sample has the same value, and model gave all-zero coefficients. Might not be same issue as yours but might be a method to debug your code.